# Struts2 dynamic parameter name in redirect-action

Tags: java, url, redirect, struts2

I'm successfully using a redirect-action for one of my struts2 mapping files as follows:

```
<action name="setAsCurrentCart" class="com.fmp.MyAction">
  <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
    <param name="actionName">myOtherAction</param>
    <param name="foo">${foo}</param>
  </result>
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultComponentStack"/>
</action>
```

Here's what I want to do though:

```
<action name="setAsCurrentCart" class="com.fmp.MyAction">
  <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
    <param name="actionName">myOtherAction</param>
    <param name="${dynamicParameterName}">${dynamicParameterValue}</param>
  </result>
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultComponentStack"/>
</action>
```

In other words, I want the name of the parameter that I'm passing to be dynamic.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, that doesn't work.  However, I was able to get this working doing the following:

```
<action name="setAsCurrentCart" class="com.fmp.MyAction">
   <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
      <param name="actionName">myOtherAction</param>
      <param name="${dynamicParameterName}">${dynamicParameterValue}</param>
   </result>
</action>
```

I had just assumed it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

could you do this instead?

```
<action name="setAsCurrentCart" class="com.fmp.MyAction">
   <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
      <param name="actionName">myOtherAction</param>
      <param name="paramName">${dynamicParameterName}</param>
      <param name="paramValue">${dynamicParameterValue}</param>
   </result>
</action>
```