# How to make Named Objects accessible to another action using redirectionAction as result type in Struts2

Tags: java, session, redirect, struts2, http-redirect

I'm developing a struts2 project and I just want to know if it's possible to pass **named objects** using the redirect action as result type.

Since right now to make my named objects accessible I'm putting them in a session, but my worry is that I'm developing it in a wrong ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `String`s as dynamic (or static) parameters across `redirectAction`s.

You can also make the name dynamic, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322419/1654265).

If you need to pass Objects, the Session is good.

If the objects are too heavy, dump them on a disk, on a database, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion.